# GWT Rendering form in center Area on click of left Navigation Menu Hyper Link

Tags: java, gwt

I am new to GWT. I have created the Stack DockLayoutPanel with VerticalPanel and added the anchor link. Now my next task is render the Form on click of left Navigation Link.

Tried many ways but could not succeeded. Can somebody please help.

```
public class WebAppExample implements EntryPoint {
     StackLayoutPanel stackPanel = new StackLayoutPanel(Unit.PX);
    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        final DockLayoutPanel dockLayoutPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PX);

        Label headerLabel = new Label();
        headerLabel.setText("Example Application");
        headerLabel.addStyleName("northPanel");

        stackPanel.setPixelSize(300, 999);

        stackPanel.add(createMenuItem(),"Menus Navigation",40);

        dockLayoutPanel.addNorth(headerLabel, 48);
        dockLayoutPanel.addSouth(new FlowPanel(), 48);
        dockLayoutPanel.addWest(stackPanel,300);

        final Panel centerPanel = new FlowPanel();

        dockLayoutPanel.add(new ScrollPanel(centerPanel));
        //dockLayoutPanel.add(vPanel);

        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(dockLayoutPanel);

    }

private Widget createMenuItem() {
        // Create a popup to show the contact info when a contact is clicked
        HorizontalPanel menuPopupContainer = new HorizontalPanel();
        menuPopupContainer.setSpacing(5);
        //contactPopupContainer.add(new Image(images.defaultContact()));
        final HTML contactInfo = new HTML();
        menuPopupContainer.add(contactInfo);
        final PopupPanel contactPopup = new PopupPanel(true, false);
        contactPopup.setWidget(menuPopupContainer);

        ArrayList<String> leftMenuItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        leftMenuItems.add("Link1");


        VerticalPanel menuVPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        menuVPanel.setSpacing(4);

        for (String menu : leftMenuItems) {
            final Anchor contactLink = new Anchor(menu);
            menuVPanel.add(contactLink);
        }

        return new SimplePanel(menuVPanel);
      }
```

Comment: So we really need more details than could not succeeded. Also you might want to look at gwt ui binder for handling your layouts. It makes handling ui much easier and you can easily mix widgets and html. http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html

Answer (score 0):

When you create `Anchor` link add a `ClickHandler`:

```
contactLink.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // add the form
    }
});
```

In the handler get the form and add it (I guess) in the `centerPanel`.